# Why does my external hard drive mount as /media/TB1 instead of /media/TB?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, mount

I just added a new external USB hard drive and it's showing up in the system as TB1 when it is labeled both in the partition and in the /etc/fstab as TB.  Why is this happening?

I suspect it may be caused by the fact that (for some reason), initially, this drive was showing up as a /dev/sdi and now it's /dev/sdl.  Could that be causing this?  Might the computer have reserved /dev/sdi for "TB" and sees this other drive as a new addition and is appending a "1" to ensure the two drives are not confused?

And additionally, I'd love to know how to fix this.  Not just know why it's occurring.

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using the UUID instead of the /dev in fstab.  I got the UUID with a simple

```
sudo blkid
```

And then I just plugged in the id number instead of "/dev/sdi" in /etc/fstab.  Restarted the computer and it worked.

I still don't know WHY this happened, but have a hunch that the computer thought there were two TB drives when there was only one.  Either way, this seems to have done the trick.